# New keyboard layout does not refresh unless renamed

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

Keyboard layout names are not being released for reuse.

I am trying to create a new xkb layout. Here is how I am doing it.

- Add the new layout to /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in
- Register the layout into /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml

The layout registers well the first time around. But if I change the layout and repeat the steps above, the layout is not reloaded.

Things that didn't work:
- `setxkbmap -layout us` didn't work.
- Remove the layout completely from symbols/in and rules/evdev.xml -> logoff -> login -> re-introduce the layout -> logoff -> login.
- Restart the computer.
- Remove the layout completely from symbols/in and rules/evdev.xml -> restart -> re-introduce the layout -> restart.

Thing that worked.

- Rename the layout in evdev.xml and symbols/in each time I make changes to the layout.

I am unable to reuse a name, this is a problem obviously. This sounds like a bug to me or I am not doing things correctly.

I didn't know if the issue was with xkb (xorg), Mint or Ubuntu. So I thought I decided to start here.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1369410

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyboard layouts are compiled and cached; the cache is cleaned on reboot (I think — but I am not sure at all). What I normally do is to manually delete the cache files, which are the files that ends in `.xkm` in 
`/var/lib/xkb/`.

```
cd /var/lib/xkb/
rm *.xkm
```

(as root, or add the appropriate `sudo`).

[(Data form my blog post on modifying layouts).](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/)